# Could not find or load main class M - hadoop windows

Tags: windows, hadoop, installation

I am new to hadoop and I am trying to set up hadoop on windows 10. I downloaded the hadoop version 2.7.3 tar.gz from Apache website. These are the steps I have done:

1. Extracted the tar.gz into a folder in C:\ ---> C:\hadoop
2. Created and set the HADOOP_HOME environment variable to C:\hadoop
3. Updated the PATH environment variable by adding C:\hadoop\bin
4. Added the JAVA_HOME environment variable and set it to the jdk home folder.

The issue is that, any Hadoop related command I execute gives me the following error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class M

For example, I get this error even on executing the following command:`hadoop version`

I read a lot of related posts on stackoverflow, and tried the different suggestions such as updating hadoop-env.sh, hadoop-config.sh, repeated the whole set up process multiple times. The other posts here seem to refer to errors that deal with specific classes, however, the error I face does not provide any class name, it just says class M.
I am not sure what the problem is, and nothing I do seems to work. Could anyone please let me know what is wrong and how I could solve this issue?

Answer (score 13):

The problem may be related to the syntax of your system username. In such case, go to your Hadoop directory and edit /etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.cmd

Near the end of the file you'll find:

```
set HADOOP_IDENT_STRING=%USERNAME%
```

change it to whatever name you want, but one NOT containing a space, eg.:

```
set HADOOP_IDENT_STRING=myuser
```

hope this will help

Comment: it really cause of username on windows

Answer (score 0):

I ran the command using the **command prompt as Administrator**.
It worked for me. I am not sure if it's necessary to set the username.

Answer (score -2):

Removing username from set HADOOP_IDENT_STRING=%USERNAME% or giving it a name which does not have a space solves the problem.