# Hadoop 2.7.1 on Windows 10 throws the exception "could not find or load mY class"

Tags: java, hadoop

I installed Hadoop 2.7.1 on Windows 64 bit which I downloaded this [site](https://github.com/karthikj1/Hadoop-2.7.1-Windows-64-binaries/releases). But the problem is hdfs command does not work at all. When I execute hdfs command, it throws the following error message:

> Could not find or load mY class.

The JAVA_HOME and HADOOP_HOME, YARN_HOME is configured correctly. However the commands throws this exception message whenever it is executed.

Comment: `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` is not set correctly

Comment: I appreciate your reply. Kindly advise me the sample file or reference site including HADOOP_CLASSPATH configfration. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, first Hadoop may "work" on Windows, but it will not be as smooth as using Linux. Start here. http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html

Comment: it works well. The answer is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39634291/could-not-find-or-load-main-class-m-hadoop-windows. Thanks any way ; )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find or load main class M - hadoop windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39634291/could-not-find-or-load-main-class-m-hadoop-windows)